# How to configure correctly FOS Elastica analyzers and filters?

Tags: symfony, search, analyzer, elastica, foselasticabundle

In my symfony2 application, I am using FOS Elastica bundle to perform searches.

I have tried to set up analyzers and filters but it seems they just have no effect. For instance, if I search for the word 'cake', the objects containing the sentence case 'Cake' won't be returned.

How can I configure those analyzers and filters correctly ?

My config :

```
#Elastic Search
fos_elastica:
    default_manager: orm
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        website:
            client: default
            settings:
                index:
                    analysis:
                        analyzer:
                            custom_index_analyzer :
                                type     :    custom
                                tokenizer:    nGram
                                filter   :    [stopwords, asciifolding ,lowercase, snowball, elision, worddelimiter]
                            custom_search_analyzer :
                                type     :    custom
                                tokenizer:    nGram
                                filter   :    [stopwords, asciifolding ,lowercase, snowball, elision, worddelimiter]
                        tokenizer:
                            nGram:
                                type:     nGram
                                min_gram: 1
                                max_gram: 2
                        filter:
                            snowball:
                                type:     snowball
                                language: French
                            elision:
                                type:     elision
                                articles: [l, m, t, qu, n, s, j, d]
                            stopwords:
                                type:      stop
                                stopwords: [_french_]
                                ignore_case : true
                            worddelimiter :
                                type:      word_delimiter
            index_name: foodmeup
            types:
                recipe:
                    mappings:
                        name:
                            boost: 5
                            index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                            search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                        nickName:
                            index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                            search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                        content:
                            index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                            search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                        recipeIngredients:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                name:
                                    index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                                    search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                                product:
                                    type: "nested"
                                    properties:
                                        name: { type: string, boost: 10}
                                        nickName: { type: string }
                                        content: { type: string }
                                        tags:
                                            type: "nested"
                                            boost: 5
                                            properties:
                                                name: { type: string }
                        userRecipes:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                name:
                                    index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                                    search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                                content:
                                    index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                                    search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                        tags:
                            type: "nested"
                            boost: 5
                            properties:
                                name:
                                    index_analyzer : custom_index_analyzer
                                    search_analyzer : custom_search_analyzer
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\Recipe
                        repository: AppBundle\Repository\FoodAnalytics\RecipeRepository
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
                        listener: ~ # by default, listens to "insert", "update" and "delete"
                product:
                    mappings:
                        name: { type: string, boost: 10}
                        nickName: { type: string }
                        content: { type: string }
                        userIngredients:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                name: { type: string }
                                content: { type: string }
                        tags:
                            type: "nested"
                            boost: 5
                            properties:
                                name: { type: string }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\MarketPlace\Product
                        repository: AppBundle\Repository\MarketPlace\ProductRepository
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
                        listener: ~ # by default, listens to "insert", "update" and "delete"
                user:
                    mappings:
                        firstName: { type: string, boost: 3}
                        lastName: { type: string, boost: 10 }
                        content: { type: string }
                        username: { type: string }
                        email: { type: string }
                        jobSeeker:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                skills:
                                    type: "nested"
                                    properties:
                                        name: { type: string }
                                experiences:
                                    type: "nested"
                                    properties:
                                        position:
                                            type: "nested"
                                            properties:
                                                name: { type: string }
                                        content: { type: string }
                                trainings:
                                    type: "nested"
                                    properties:
                                        name: { type: string }
                                        content: { type: string }
                                        diploma:
                                            type: "nested"
                                            properties:
                                                name: { type: string }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\User\User
                        repository: AppBundle\Repository\User\UserRepository
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
                        listener: ~ # by default, listens to "insert", "update" and "delete"
                organization:
                    mappings:
                        name: { type: string, boost: 10}
                        legalName: { type: string, boost: 10}
                        shortDescription: { type: string, boost: 3}
                        route: { type: string}
                        content: { type: string }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\User\Organization
                        repository: AppBundle\Repository\User\OrganizationRepository
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
                        listener: ~ # by default, listens to "insert", "update" and "delete"
                offer:
                    mappings:
                        name: { type: string, boost: 10}
                        content: { type: string }
                        responsibilities: { type: string }
                        skills:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                name: { type: string }
                        contractType:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                name: { type: string }
                        position:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                name: { type: string, boost: 10 }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Job\Offer
                        repository: AppBundle\Repository\Job\OfferRepository
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
                        listener: ~
                post:
                    mappings:
                        name: { type: string, boost: 10}
                        content: { type: string }
                        summary: { type: string }
                        tags:
                            type: "nested"
                            boost: 5
                            properties:
                                name: { type: string }
                        comments:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                content: { type: string }
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Social\Post
                        repository: AppBundle\Repository\Social\PostRepository
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
                        listener: ~
```

The query is a basic one :

```
$finder = $this->container->get('website.recipe')
$elasticaResults = $finder->find($search);
```

Comment: How can we help you without the query ...

Comment: well, the query is working fine, this is the config that needs some setup. I've added the query in case it changes something but I don't believe so... or am I mistaking?

Comment: At first glance, your config file seems fine (at least for me).

I have few questions:  

- have you populate the index with any kind of data?

        php app/console f:e:p --index=website

- do you have test your query using the [head plugin](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/)?

I moved my "answer" in this comment.

Comment: Check if your mapping is correct in elasticsearch: GET /website/_mapping

Comment: Try to put the lowercase filter in first position.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you update your `fos_elastica` `config` file, you need in a first time to update the index(es) with the command:

```
php app/console fos:elastica:populate --index website --type= <<you type>>
```

This command will reindex your data with erasing previous one. In a second time, you should have to check your mapping information to check everything is fine and synchronous.

You could check your analyser with this command:

```
curl 'http://<< yourdomain >>:9200/website/_analyze?pretty=true&analyzer=custom_french_analyzer' -d "Cake"
```